# Quickest way to let Google know a site no longer has SSL?

Tags: google-search-console, https, bing-webmaster-tools

I've removed SSL from a website, permanently.

I would like Google (and other search engines) to pick this up ASAP as of course people will be seeing a warning/error in their browser when they click on the search engine result which still thinks my site is https://

Is there a way to tell Google and Bing that my site is no longer https://, other than simply submitting it for crawling again? Maybe some tool within their respective webmaster tools areas?

Thanks

Comment: Submitting a site for crawling generally does almost nothing.  Why are you removing HTTPS?    If anything you should be moving to only HTTPS.   Browsers, especially Chrome are starting to mark all HTTP sites as insecure.   Pretty soon the only way to have a website without scary warnings will be to use HTTPS.

Answer (score 2):

While there isn't a way to tell search engines that, specifically, your security protocol has changed, and I agree with @Stephen that you should have left the secure version up, here's a general checklist that would also apply to other scenarios of website/URL changes and canonicalization.

- Do resubmit your XML sitemap to Google and Bing, but make sure that it has the updated URL's in it only.
- Make sure that your old URL's 301 redirect to your new URL's.
- Make sure your canonical tags on every page point to the new version.
- Update your Google Search Console and Bing Webmaster Tools to ensure you're tracking both versions, just in case.
- Update your Analytics too.
- Go though the website and make sure all the internal links pointing to various pages are updated with the new URL.